# Error "file not found: -fobjc-arc" on compiling IOS App in XCode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, linker

after adding the OCMock framework i got that strange error... :(

```
ld: file not found: -fobjc-arc
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

It looks like if the compiler flag tries to be loaded by XCode?

Any idea?

Best regards, hijolan

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: Look at the build output in the Log Navigator.  If you cannot figure it out then post it here.

Comment: hi... thank you for your reply... that code above came from the log navigator... i now reverted my project file by git and added the library again.. ;) it works now.

Comment: I'm getting this error now - I've edited the question to add in the log navigator output.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was getting the exact same error on Xcode 4.3.2.  Here's my navigator log; I'm adding it for Google juice.

```
Ld /Users/makdad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Journal-bfkvfbsrkmrsjpddzfmwrstjfkzr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/JournalTests.octest/JournalTests normal i386
cd /Users/makdad/Documents/MT/mt-mobile/iOS/Journal
setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -bundle -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk -L/Users/phooze/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Journal-bfkvfbsrkmrsjpddzfmwrstjfkzr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/phooze/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Journal-bfkvfbsrkmrsjpddzfmwrstjfkzr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks -filelist /Users/phooze/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Journal-bfkvfbsrkmrsjpddzfmwrstjfkzr/Build/Intermediates/Journal.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/JournalTests.build/Objects-normal/i386/JournalTests.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -bundle_loader /Users/phooze/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Journal-bfkvfbsrkmrsjpddzfmwrstjfkzr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Journal.app/Journal -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -ObjC -force_load -fobjc-arc -ftest-coverage -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=40100 -lOCMock -framework Twitter -framework MapKit -framework MobileCoreServices -framework SystemConfiguration -lxml2 -licucore -framework CoreData -framework CoreGraphics -framework CFNetwork -framework QuartzCore -framework SenTestingKit -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -o /Users/phooze/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Journal-bfkvfbsrkmrsjpddzfmwrstjfkzr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/JournalTests.octest/JournalTests
```

The OCMock instructions explicitly ask you to add linker flags -- `-ObjC` and `-force_load`.

`-force_load` is expecting a value -- see [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906147/what-does-the-all-load-linker-flag-do) that explains that `-all_load` is what to use if you don't want to specify a library name.

As someone who just spent 25 minutes on this, I should check again with the OCMock tutorial -- I don't think it was very clear in this instruction.

[This blog post](http://www.infinite-loop.dk/blog/2011/04/using-mock-objects-to-stabilize-unit-tests/) has a much better image that shows exactly how your settings should look.

Comment: As a note, `-all_load` and `-force_load` should no longer be necessary on LLVM in Xcode 4.2 and higher: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7942924/19679 . At one point, they were required due to a linker bug, but that issue has since been resolved in the latest versions of LLVM. You should be able to drop the linker flags other than `-ObjC`.

Comment: @BradLarson thanks for the clarification.  That's how it always goes... people add voodoo magic to get around a bug, but when the bug is fixed, no one ever goes around "the Internet" and cleans up the mess of old workaround posts.