# ld: file not found: -fobjc-arc

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

When I try build my project, I get an error:

```
ld: file not found: -fobjc-arc
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Previously, everything worked, the problem appeared after upgrade TapJoy lib.

Xcode 5, iOS 7.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10529691/error-file-not-found-fobjc-arc-on-compiling-ios-app-in-xcode

Answer (score -2):

Open other linker flags

Add

> -fobjC-arc

And, go to Heaader Search Path , and give the path of the lib file