# Linker error while using KIF on xcode6

Tags: ios, objective-c, linker-errors, kif, kif-framework

When i'm trying to use KIF, I get this linker error. Anybody know what is it?

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/Framework'
ld: file not found: -fobjc-arc
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Thanks for any idea.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error "file not found: -fobjc-arc" on compiling IOS App in XCode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10529691/error-file-not-found-fobjc-arc-on-compiling-ios-app-in-xcode)

Answer (score 0):

I had this happen many times to me. Every time it was because I missed a step in the installation of KIF. Go back to the installation instructions and ensure you set all the configurations correctly. Pay special attention to the instructions for header paths. I am on my phone right now or else I would be able to give you the exact settings. Go double check the instructions. If your settings are correct reply here with that info and we can try to figure it out together. First though make sure these things are correct. Once you do, clean your project (Cmd-shift-K), close project, delete your derived data (preferably through Terminal) and then try to build again).